# Change value of observable returned by mocked service for each test in Angular/Jasmine/Redux

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, ngrx

I have a service that returns the values exposed by ngrx selectors.
A component defines this service to get data.
I am writing unit tests for the component using a mock of the service, and I need the mock service to return different values for each unit test.
How can I achieve this?

**Component**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-test',
    templateUrl: './test.component.html',
    providers: [TestService],

})
    export class TestComponent {

        test$ = this.testService.test$;
        test: number;

        constructor(private service: TestService) {
            service.test$.subscribe(test => this.test = test);
        }
    }
```

**Service**

```
export class TestService {

        test$ = this.store.select(getTestValueFromStore);

        constructor(private store: Store<any>){}
}
```

**Attempt 1 (reset the value of the service): does not work**

```
class MockTestService {
    **test$ = of(10);**
}

describe('TestComponent', () => {
    let testService: TestService;

    beforeEach((() => {
        // Define component service
        TestBed.overrideComponent(
            TestComponent,
            { set: { providers: [{ provide: TestService, useClass: MockTestService }] } }
        );

        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [TestComponent]
        })
            .compileComponents();
    }));

    beforeEach(async() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        testService = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(TestService);
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });

it('should do something when the value returned by the service is 20', fakeAsync(() => {

        **testService.test$ = of(20);**

        tick();

        expect(component.test).toEqual(20);
    }));
});
```

**Attempt 2: use subjects. Karma throws error 
"Property 'next' does not exist on type 'Observable'"
because TestService returns observables, not subjects**

```
class MockTestService {
        **test$ = new BehaviourSubject(10);**
    }

    describe('TestComponent', () => {
        let testService: TestService;

        beforeEach((() => {
            // Define component service
            TestBed.overrideComponent(
                TestComponent,
                { set: { providers: [{ provide: TestService, useClass: MockTestService }] } }
            );

            TestBed.configureTestingModule({
                declarations: [TestComponent]
            })
                .compileComponents();
        }));

        beforeEach(async() => {
            fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
            component = fixture.componentInstance;
            testService = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(TestService);
            fixture.detectChanges();
        });

    it('should do something when the value returned by the service is 20', fakeAsync(() => {

            **testService.test$.next(20);**

            tick();

            expect(component.test).toEqual(20);
        }));
    });
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You said in your question that you want "the mock service to return different values for each unit test."  To do this you are going to have to make some changes to the way your component is defined.

1. The most important change is to move the subscription into ngOnInit() and out of the constructor for your component.  If you do this, then you can control when the subscription fires, otherwise it will fire when the component is created making it very difficult to return different values for each unit test.
2. Once that is done, then you need to be careful where you call `fixture.detectChanges()`.  This is because that will execute `ngOnInit()`, which will execute the subscription and store the value returned from the Observable into `component.test`.  Note that since you are using `of()` it will simply emit once and then complete.  It will not emit again if you put a new value into `testService.test$`.
3. Once you have this set up, then you can change the value of `testService.test$` BEFORE you call fixture.detectChanges and make the values whatever you would like.

I have set up a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-q-54176001?file=app%2Fmy.component.spec.ts) to demonstrate this, changing your code as little as possible just to get it to work.  There are two tests, each testing different values returned.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. This works based on the code in my question, but if I then want to change the value returned by the service after the component is initialise, how can I mock that? I have added this https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-q-54176001-frxnf5 so you can see what I mean. Maybe I need to ask a new question for this.

Comment: Yes, do ask it as a new question, it's a good one.  The solution will involve refactoring your code to use a Subject or a BehaviorSubject depending on how you want it to behave.  Documentation [here](http://reactivex.io/documentation/subject.html).  While you set that up, I'll work on re-doing the StackBlitz with a Subject to show you what I mean.

Comment: I have tried to make it work with BehaviourSubjects and it works, but TypeScript doesn't like that the mock service interface is different from the real service. I have asked a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54191645/unit-test-mocking-service-that-returns-observables-to-return-subjects-in-order

Comment: Kudos for the `fixture.detectChanges` tip!

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
describe('TestComponent', () => {
    beforeEach((() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [TestComponent],
            providers: [
              { provide: TestService, useValue: { test$: of(20) } }
            ]
        })
            .compileComponents();
    }));

    beforeEach(async() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        testService = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(TestService);
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });

   it('should do something when the value returned by the service is 20', () => {
        expect(component.test).toEqual(20);
    });
});
```

You do not need to use fakeAsync here, because `of()` emits synchronously.

Also, please consider subscribing to the observable in the `ngOnInit` hook. Constructor should be used for dependency injection only.

Comment: Thanks. So if I wanted to add another test when the service returns a different value, how would I do that? Do I need to configure the testing module before every test?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to test a non-component Angular item (ie AuthGuard with Service dependencies), you won't be able to use the fixture.detectChanges() trick as you won't have a component to detect changes for.

In this case you should use a spy:

```
describe('AuthGuardTest', () => {
    let testBed: TestBed;
    let authGuard: AuthGuard;
    let testService: TestService;

    beforeEach(() => {
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
        providers: [AuthGuard]
      });

      testBed = getTestBed();
      testService = testBed.inject(TestService);
      authGuard = testBed.inject(AuthGuard);
    });

    it('should return 1000', () => {
      // Mock the method in your testService to return 1000
      spyOn(testService, 'getNumber').and.returnValue(1000);

      // Call code that references testService.getNumber() and Assert 1000 was returned
    });

    it('should return 2000', () => {
      // Mock the method in your testService to return 2000
      spyOn(testService, 'getNumber').and.returnValue(2000);

      // Call code that references testService.getNumber() and Assert 2000 was returned
    });
});
```

For more examples check out these tutorials:

Mocks and Spies - https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/unit-testing/mocks-and-spies/

Unit Testing AuthGuard - https://keepgrowing.in/angular/how-to-test-angular-authguard-examples-for-the-canactivate-interface/