# Unit test: Mocking service that returns observables to return subjects in order to test change of values over time causes TS to throw TS2339

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, observable, behaviorsubject

I have a service that returns the values exposed by ngrx selectors, and a component that defines this service, injects it and sets properties based on the values returned by the service.

I am writing unit tests for the component using a mock of the service, and I need the mock service to return different values for each unit test. 
In order to do this I have defined the mock service class so it returns subjects instead of observables. The tests run, but TS throws an error saying that the interface of the mock service does not match the interface of the real service, as the real service returns observables.

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-q-54176001-frxnf5?file=app%2Fmy.component.spec.ts)

The stackblitz works and the tests run correctly, but as you can see TS throws the error
TS2339: Property 'next' does not exist on type 'Observable'

I have found I can add
// @ts-ignore
above each call to .next() to tell the TypeScript compiler to ignore the error, but this doesn't seem to be the best solution.

Maybe there is a better way of mocking the service altogether so it still returns observables but I can return a different value for each unit test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have the real service AND the mock return the same thing, using the `.asObservable()` method on the BehaviorSubject.  You could also use the `do()` method you have to set a new value into the BehaviorSubject.

To demonstrate, I put together this [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-q-54176001-update1?file=app%2Fmy.component.spec.ts).  Here is the MockTestService from that StackBlitz:

```
MockTestService {
    private _test$ = new BehaviorSubject(10);
    public test$ = this._test$.asObservable();
    do(param: number): void { this._test$.next(param); }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: This does indeed work but it seems like an overkill to have to define every class property as a BehaviourSubject, subscribe to each selector manually (and manage that subscription) and copy that value to the service property to then convert it to an observable just so the unit tests compile. I have found another solution is to cast the mock service to any, although this is still not ideal at least it doesn't imply changing the logic to adapt to the unit tests. Thanks for your help

Comment: Glad you got it sorted.  :)